# How to check all of your email accounts from Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail, gmail-pop

i been looking for an application that would check all my added emails to Gmail, but i didn't find any. i found a lot of ways to send emails and so on. but is there any app that would check it intervally ?

i looked at Gmail API, and i found nothing ? so what do you think ?

Comment: [I (pronoun)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_(pronoun))

Answer (score 0):

I would use [imap](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Message_Access_Protocol) access (see gmail [doc](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75726) and [this too](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=75725)).

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps you: [mail-gate](http://haibison.com/apps/mail-gate). It's Java based and open source  :-)